# Function does not plot

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

I am sry to ask this probably very basic question. I do not get, where I made an error using the following Plot function:

```
func[x_] := dataA0[Select[#age == x &], "absences"][Mean] // N

Plot[Evaluate@func[x], {x, 1, 22}, PlotRange -> All]
```

I tried the answers given to similar issues on stackexchange but up to now I did not find the solution. The function itself gives correct results.

Is the fact that the given function is not continuos maybe an issue here?

Comment: Please specify the programming language you are using as tag.

Comment: I'm guessing this is Mathematica

Comment: Yeah sry, its Mathematica

Comment: It's very difficult to test your code without `dataA0` but the first thing you should do is drop the trailing `//N` from the function definition.

Comment: My initial guess is that you are using the wrong function as `Plot` plots a continuous function and that is not what you have.  See [`DiscretePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretePlot.html). Hard to help without some information on the contents of `dataA0`.